# What is the role of << , >> operators in the loop

Tags: c++, c++11

I have never seen using << operator in a loop.

Could someone please let me know what role are these operators << , >> playing in this loop.

```
for(i=step << 1; i>=0;i-=2)             
        {
         // normal
         Normal(angles[i>>1]

      }
```

Comment: Its a left- and a rightshift.

Comment: This depends on the type of `i` and `step`. If it's a numeric primitive it's a bitshift. If it's a class it's not possible to answer this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i >> 1` is a silly way of writing `i / 2` assuming `i` is an appropriate integral type.

`step << 1` is a silly way of writing `step * 2`, assuming `step` is an appropriate integral type.

Comment: I wouldn't qualify that 'silly' in general: `uint32_t address = byte3 << 24 | byte2 << 16 | byte1 << 8 | byte 0` vs. `address = byte3 * 16777216 + byte2 * 65536 + byte1 * 256 + byte0`...

Comment: @Aconcagua: Indeed it's useful when setting up bitwise eumerations for example, but in the case the OP presents it's utter madness.

Comment: It's not even clear if we are talking about numeric values in this question.

Comment: @ThomasSablik: Indeed. To go further down the rabbit hole it's tempting to think that `i >> 1` must be integral due to it being used as an array index. But perhaps `angles` is a `std::vector` (which allows a floating point type to be passed to `[]` which is about as ugly as the C++ standard library gets), or `angles` might be an instance of a class with an overloaded `[]`. I plumped for simplicity in this answer and used "assuming" and "appropriate" to cover off complications.

Comment: @Bathsheba `std::vector::operator[]` accepting floating point types is new to me... Unfortunately, there's an implicit conversion, so *that*'s why it works...

Comment: @Aconcagua: Even back in the day they could have used a series of overloads to `const &` types according to the toolset.

Comment: Actually, I'm a bit unhappy about my initial comment having started such an intense debate... As we calculate `-= 2` afterwards I'd rather assume doing calculation on numeric values as well, and I agree that multiplication might have been better choice in *given* case. All I wanted to express is that wording appears too general to me, disqualifying the shifts even in cases where they are appropriate...

Comment: @Aconcagua: Na, it was fun.

Comment: @Aconcagua we don't know what [] , what Normal, angles, i, step are.. those operators and objects literally can be anything :P

Answer (score 1):

These are [bitwise shift operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic):

> Bitwise shift operators The bitwise shift operator expressions have
>   the form
>
> lhs << rhs    (1)
>
> lhs >> rhs    (2)
>
> 1) left shift of lhs by rhs bits
>
> 2) right shift of lhs by rhs bits
>
> For the built-in operators, lhs and
>   rhs must both have integral or unscoped enumeration type. Integral
>   promotions are performed on both operands. The return type is the type
>   of the left operand after integral promotions.